# Event interaction between JQuery + Pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, event-handling

I'm writing a plugin which will eventually be used on different sites. The plugin communicates with the rest of the page on an event basis. So far so good.

Now here is the catch: Some existing sites use pure JS to listen and dispatch events, some use JQuery. The plugin itself should not use jQuery (for different reasons) but only pure JS.
So the goal is basically to listen to and dispatch jQuery-like events without jQuery.

How can pure JS Events and jQuery Events work together, especially with custom data attached to the event?

```
Dispatcher      Listener        Event Triggered     Event Data Transmitted

JS              JS              yes                 yes (event.detail)
JS              jQuery          yes                 no
jQuery          JS              no                  no
jQuery          jQuery          yes                 yes (payload)
```

Here is the codepen:
https://codepen.io/st_h_/pen/WNMYPBQ

Answer (score 1):

JQuery has it's own event's layer on top of Vanilla so it's not really possible to catch JQuery events in Vanilla JavaScript.

One option is to use JQuery to listen for and repeat them as normal DOM events, witch is exactly what [jquery-events-to-dom-events](https://github.com/leastbad/jquery-events-to-dom-events) does.

But then your still using JQuery, kinda...

Comment: Since jQuery itself is also pure JS, it should imo be possible to access/emulate the jQuery event layer. Do you know about some resources or documentation about this event layer?

Comment: I have very little knowledge of the inner-workings of JQuery, so I can't rule it out as completely impossible to catch JQuery events in Vanilla. However, everything I have seen on the subject indicates that JQuery events are basically in their own little world and untouchable my mere mortal JavaScript.

Comment: I don't want to include this in my answer, because it is pure speculation, but... You /might/ be able to put Jquery-handling code in try-catch blocks, and just not include JQuery in your plugin. So, if the page already has JQuery, your `try{$('thing').bind('event);` will work, but if JQuery isn't being used it just errors out and the `catch{}` (hopefully) keeps the whole thing from crashing. This is pure speculation though, so take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for linking a codepen to your code :D

First thing you need to do is "convert" your jQuery element to a "pure JS" one. By doing a `.get(0)`, you can now use the `dispatchEvent` function with a `CustomEvent` we would be making with the input value as the `detail` option, it really needs to be **detail** and not **value**.

```js
$button.bind("click", () => {
  const event = new CustomEvent('update', { detail: $input.val() });
  $h1.get(0).dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

And then the only change you'd need to make to your even listener would be to use `detail` property instead of `value`.

```js
_h1.addEventListener("update", function(e){
  this.innerText = e.detail || "no event.detail"
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. So this works when using jquery to dispatch a pure js event. 
But I do *not* want to use jquery; So how can i do the oposite (dispatch a jquery-like event with pure js, and get the payload from a jquery event with a pure js event listener)

Comment: What? I'm not sure I totally get what you need... You want to make a JavaScript event listener listening to a jQuery event? If so, I think that's almost impossible unless using `jquery-events-to-dom-events`, you can't make JavaScript listen to added layers.

Comment: Coemu is building a plugin that must be Vanilla JS, and must run on pages that use JQuery and those that do not. So the problem is, how to we get Vanilla to interact with JQuery events when they are there? Which might be a "give me a salary, six months, and all the energy drinks I can take without dying" problem.